# C++ in iOS Development issues

Tags: c++, ios

So I have a .h file and when I include iostream xcode says that header file doesnt exist. But what is making me mad is that whenever I go though the new file process choosing c++ class the default .h file comes with one line of code, which includes iostream.h
so when I import that to my Objective-C code it fails to compile.

Comment: Is the default really `iostream.h`? That's not standard C++. Many implementations provide it for backward compatibility with pre-standard versions of C++, but the standard has been around for fifteen years, and code that uses `iostream.h` should be long gone. Maybe Apple hasn't gotten the word.

Comment: Is it just me being ignorant, or isn't iOS dev done in Objective-C, which *doesn't* have things like `iostream`s?

Comment: @Drise Although every iOS app must use Objective-C (because the system frameworks require it), you can choose to write some parts of your app in C++.  The easiest way to call C++ in an iOS app is to use Objective-C++, which takes the Objective-C extensions to C and adds them to C++.

Comment: @robmayoff That's sounds horribly complicated and silly; why not just cut the crap and use C++?

Comment: @Drise To repeat: "every iOS app must use Objective-C".  The system requires you to define at least one Objective-C class (your application delegate).  Comments on this question are not a good place to discuss the benefits of Objective-C and Objective-C++.  If you want to know more, post a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put `#include <iostream>` in a `.h` file, then you must be sure to only include that `.h` file in C++ files (`.cpp` or `.cc`) or Objective-C++ files (`.mm`).  You're getting a compiler error because you're including your `.h` file in a C (`.c`) or Objective-C (`.m`) file.

Comment: If I dont include (import) it then how do I use it in the project?

Comment: @user1580785 - you put the `#include <iostream>` directive in the .cpp file.

Comment: @Pete Becker but then how is any of my code in the cpp file ever going to run?

Comment: @user1580785 You probably just want to rename some or all of your `.m` files to `.mm`.  That makes them Objective-C++, which means you can include C++-specific header files and use C++ functions and classes.

Comment: @robmayoff That worked great, quick question though do I have to use Obj C++ to use C++ it's not a problem for me (I actually kinda like the idea of using both in one file). Actually more to the point are there any down sides to using Obj C++ from what I've read it has some issues beyond obj-c and c++.

Comment: If you are proficient with C++, the only downside to using Objective-C++ (instead of just Objective-C) is that compilation might be slightly slower.  You probably won't notice.

Comment: Actually, there are some upsides to using C++.  Specifically, when using ARC, you can maintain objective-c objects in normal C++ data structures, and the compiler will automatically handle all the ARC magic.